# How to map custom keys in Open AI gym games?

Tags: python, openai-gym

I was trying to enable the CarRacing-v0 environment to be played by user using custom keys I thought I could have this using utils.play like this:

```
import gym
from gym.utils.play import *

play(gym.make("CarRacing-v0"))
```

It works fine for the atari environments but in this case I got

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-080385c697d2> in <module>()
      8 # play.keys_to_action = KEYWORD_TO_KEY
      9 
---> 10 play(gym.make("CarRacing-v0"))
     11 
     12 # mapping of keys

~/Documents/openai/gym/gym/utils/play.py in play(env, transpose, fps, zoom, callback, keys_to_action)
     92         else:
     93             assert False, env.spec.id + " does not have explicit key to action mapping, " + \
---> 94                           "please specify one manually"
     95     relevant_keys = set(sum(map(list, keys_to_action.keys()),[]))
     96 

AssertionError: CarRacing-v0 does not have explicit key to action mapping, please specify one manually
```

So I was wondering how to do this custom action mapping?
The comment in the play code says it's a mapping keys_to_action: dict: tuple(int) -> int

The atari_env does it this way:

```
KEYWORD_TO_KEY = {
            'UP':      ord('w'),
            'DOWN':    ord('s'),
            'LEFT':    ord('a'),
            'RIGHT':   ord('d'),
            'FIRE':    ord(' '),
        }
```

I know the car_racing script does this by capturing the keys pressed into an 3 element array and passing that value to env.step. So I tried a similar way here:

```
KEYWORD_TO_KEY = {'STEER':ord('a'),'GAS':ord('w'),'BREAK':ord('s')}
play.keys_to_action = KEYWORD_TO_KEY
```

It didn't work. I know steer is wrong but I thought I'd get at least the vehicle turning one way.
Then I checked remapping the keywords to a custom combination on one of the Atari games.
The game worked but the key mapping was the original not my modification.

Do you guys have any idea how to do this custom key mapping properly?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with play from pygame. I also included in comments how other gym envs could be played.

```
import pygame
import gym
from gym.utils.play import play        
import numpy as np 
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

# mapping = {(pygame.K_LEFT,): 0, (pygame.K_RIGHT,): 1}
# play(gym.make("CartPole-v0"), keys_to_action=mapping)

# mapping = {(pygame.K_LEFT,): 0, (pygame.K_RIGHT,): 2}
# play(gym.make("MountainCar-v0"), keys_to_action=mapping, noop=0)

mapping = {"w": np.array([0, 0.7, 0]),
            "a": np.array([-1, 0, 0]),
            "s": np.array([0, 0, 1]),
            "d": np.array([1, 0, 0]),
            "wa": np.array([-1, 0.7, 0]),
            "dw": np.array([1, 0.7, 0]),
            "ds": np.array([1, 0, 1]),
            "as": np.array([-1, 0, 1]),
            }
default_action = np.array([0,0,0])
play(gym.make("CarRacing-v2"), keys_to_action=mapping, noop=default_action)
```

Comment: B.t.w. This also works in the new [gymnasium](https://gymnasium.farama.org) environment using `from gymnasium.utils.play import play`.  But to get it to work I had to use pygame 2.1.0 (python 3.9).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that works outside of play(). This gives you the opportunity to record human actions and use them for learning.

```
def register_input(a):
    global quit, restart
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                a[0] = -1.0
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                a[0] = +1.0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                a[1] = +1.0
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                a[2] = +0.8  
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                restart = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                quit = True            
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                a[0] = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                a[0] = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                a[1] = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                a[2] = 0            
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit = True

action = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
env = gym.make(environment_name, render_mode="human")

quit = False
while not quit:
    env.reset()
    total_reward = 0.0
    steps = 0
    restart = False
    while True:
        register_input(action)
        s, r, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(action)
        total_reward += r
        if steps % 200 == 0 or terminated or truncated:
            print("\naction " + str([f"{x:+0.2f}" for x in action]))
            print(f"step {steps} total_reward {total_reward:+0.2f}")
        steps += 1
        if terminated or truncated or restart or quit:
            break
env.close()
```